# What does it mean to deploy a branch to localhost:port?

Tags: git, deployment, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm examining the StrongLoop or LoopBack framework (do not know what is the difference, they have it very confusing). And I play with their `slc deploy` command. The `slc deploy -h` says:

```
Deploy a node application to a StrongLoop process manager

Examples:

Deploy 'deploy' branch to localhost:
        slc deploy

Deploy 'deploy' branch to a remote host:
        slc deploy http://prod1.example.com

Deploy to a remote host, on a non-standard port, using authentication:
        slc deploy http://user:pass@prod1.example.com:8765

Deploy 'production' branch to localhost:
        slc deploy http://localhost production
```

I tried to deploy to localhost. And now no any `slc ctl ...` commands work. And I cannot see `localhost` sites in my browser, no server running. Here is what I did:

```
C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hi>slc deploy
Counting objects: 4295, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3925/3925), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4295/4295), 6.27 MiB | 4.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 4295 (delta 695), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://127.0.0.1:8701/default
 * [new branch]      deploy -> deploy
Deployed `deploy` to `http://127.0.0.1:8701`

C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hi>slc ctl status
Command status failed with Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

It says `Deployed 'deploy' to 'http://127.0.0.1:8701'`. And what does it mean? I try to open `http://127.0.0.1:8701` in a browser but get:
[image]

And now no any `slc ctl ...` commands work. The output is `Command status failed with Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`.

My question are:

1. What does it mean "Deploy a branch to localhost"? What is happening after running this command?
2. Why I get `Command status failed with Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` after I have deployed a branch to localhost?
3. How to roll everything back?

Answer (score 1):

When it says `Deployed 'deploy' to 'http://127.0.0.1:8701'` it means that you have deployed the `deploy` branch to the PM instance that is running on `127.0.0.1:8701`. Note that that is the URL for PM, not your app.

As the developer, the port that your app listens on is up to you. It is conventional to write your app to use the `PORT` environment variable to determine which port your app should listen on.

To set the environment variable for your app while running under pm you would use something like `slc ctl env-set PORT=3000`. Depending on your setup you may need to use `slc ctl -C http://127.0.0.1:8701 env-set PORT=3000` (you would need the same `-C URL` option for `slc ctl status` as well).